# Cisco sg500-24p web-based configuration utility ip adress

Tags: cisco, vlan

How can i know what is the ip adress to the web-based control panel for my Cisco sg500 if it is not the default and if i don't want to rest the switch, i need to change vlan for a port ?

The switch is already diveded into 3 vlan, the port 24 located on vlan 1 with ip 192.168.47.5

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to plug a console cable into the console port and configure it that way using a serial connection?

If you log in that way and check the config it will tell you any IP's assigned to it and if http/https access is enabled on the switch.

Comment: The problem is that i don't get any connection via console port, all my other switches have an RJ45 console port, this one have COM one. When i connect the com side to the switch and the rj45 side to my computer i don't get any connection.